# IETF, W3C, etc.: de iure or de facto standards?

Tags: standards, w3c, rfc

I keep receiving contradictory information from both web resources and uni subjects: some people consider IETF's RFCs popular but actual de facto standards and then some consider IETF an official standarization organization thus capable of emitting de iure standards.

So, are IETF, W3C and similar actually official standardization entities? Would, for example, IETF's SIP protocol considered a de iure standard?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s beyond the [scope of this site](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @lxg I know it's not a specific programming question but I found stackoverflow the most adequate StackExchange place (or let's say, less inadequate) to ask it, as standardization knowledge is necessary in certain specific programming projects, specially web implementations (also, stackoverflow was the only one where I found other questions referring to de facto/iure standards).

Comment: I agree that this is an edge case. It is true that this type of questions has been discussed in this site in the past. However, the current definition for [“on-topic” for this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) aims at „solvable“ problems. I would deem [software engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) a more suitable place for this type of questions.

Comment: @lxg okay, I'll take that into account, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standards are voluntary, unless there is a law that says that a specific standard must be used for specific products, services, procedures, etc. Even standards by official standardisation organisations are voluntary unless there is a law that enforces them.

What is an **official standardisation organisation** or not depends on the jurisdiction you are talking about. For example, in 1998 the European Commission published a [Council Directive](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/en/ALL/?uri=CELEX:31998L0034) that declared [CEN](http://www.cen.eu/), [CENELEC](https://www.cenelec.eu/) and [ETSI](http://www.etsi.org/) as official standardisation bodies for the European Union. This had several consequences, e.g. that their standards can be referred to in European law. This is not the case for W3C recommendations or IETF RFCs.

This is why, for example, the W3C's [Web Content Accessibility Guidelines](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/) needed to be integrated into European standard [EN 301 549](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/301500_301599/301549/01.01.02_60/en_301549v010102p.pdf) published by ETSI, since an ETSI standard can be referenced in European law (e.g. the European Accessibility Act).